# Computing 3D rotation matrix for camera matrix

Tags: matlab, 3d, camera, computer-vision, rotation

I'm trying to compute the camera matrix `K[R|t]` for a set of multiview images I'm generating from Blender using a plug-in. The plug-in generates the following info:

```
center_camera_x_m = -4.33945369720459
center_camera_y_m = -5.657132148742676
center_camera_z_m = 1.7091176509857178
center_camera_rx_rad = 1.4758878946304321
center_camera_ry_rad = -4.157481825473042e-08
center_camera_rz_rad = -0.6149072647094727
```

I want to generate R matrix but I'm finding the concept hard to grasp. I know that R is 3x3 matrix. I computer Rx, Ry, Rz as follow:

```
R1 = [1 0 0; 0 cos(center_camera_rx_rad) -sin(center_camera_rx_rad) ; 0 sin(center_camera_rx_rad) cos(center_camera_rx_rad)] ;
R2 = [cos(center_camera_ry_rad) 0 sin(center_camera_ry_rad) ; 0 1 0 ; -sin(center_camera_ry_rad) 0  cos(center_camera_ry_rad)] ;
R3 = [cos(center_camera_rz_rad) -sin(center_camera_rz_rad) 0 ; sin(center_camera_rz_rad) cos(center_camera_rz_rad) 0 ; 0 0 1] ;
```

I then generated the final R matrix to be used in the camera matrix by the following:

```
R = R3*R2*R1
```

Is there a way to validate the solution? and if the solution is right could someone simplify why is it calculated this way?

Comment: those are rotation matrices. There is an enitre subfield of algebra on the topic, a bit too broad to just answer here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix